# Apache 2.2.22 running a Django app shows error "client denied by server configuration"

Tags: python, django, apache, debian, mod-wsgi

I have a Debian 7.1 amd64 server with apache httpd 2.2.22 and Python 2.7.3 installed, to serve a django app which I've hooked to apache using mod_wsgi and default django `wsgi.py` script. Django is the latest 1.5.4 version with all python package dependencies in a virtualenv managed by `pip` provided with debian.

I've ran `chown -R www-data:www-data` on the entire django app and python virtualenv directories to make it work. Apache config for this virtualhost is quite minimal and follows official django guide at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/.

I've managed to make it work, except that some clients get apache (not django) 403 Forbidden error page. And apache error logfile for this virtualhost contains lines like this:

```
[client x.x.x.x] client denied by server configuration: /path/to/django/proj/app/wsgi.py
```

It works perfectly fine for other clients. What could have gone wrong?

EDIT: here is apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
ServerAdmin myname@mydomain.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_django.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_django.log combined
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

Alias /robots.txt /path/to/django/proj/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/django/proj/static/img/favicon.ico

Alias /media/ /path/to/django/proj/media/
Alias /static/ /path/to/django/proj/static/

<Directory /path/to/django/proj/media>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/django/proj/static>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/django/proj/app>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_wsgi.c>
    WSGIDaemonProcess mydomain.com processes=10 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/path/to/django/proj:/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup mydomain.com
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/django/proj/app/wsgi.py
</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you please post your apache virtual host configuration..

Comment: @RahulPatil I added the config.

Comment: once check this http://paste.ubuntu.com/6231464/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes from `mod_evasive` apache module.

I had installed Apache mod_evasive for DoS protection, and I did not know that just by installing this module it affects Apache and on Debian default (non-existing) configuration for this module is quite aggressive for modern service-based web applications.

I created `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mod-evasive.conf` as a default config for this module with higher limits and problem solved.